# Matrix vector addition

Tags: matrices, arithmetic

Given A a 3x3 matrix and B a 3x1 matrix (or column vector), I am asked to calculate A + B. Both are initially filled with one's. To my knowledge the two matrices would have to be of the same n×m dimensionions. However, if I do the addition in Python (using Numpy matrices and the '+' operator) I get a 3x3 matrix filled with two's.

How is this matrix and column vector added? Might I be misunderstanding what Python does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the addition of matrix and vector is not defined. So if you were asked to calculate such thing, you have to make it clear what he/she means.

I think [this](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLK8rPVcgrzS2oVMjMLcgvKlHITSwpyqzg5eLl8lWwhfI0oqMNdRRAKFZHARszVpOXqwybcpBEKZqEkY6CMViCl6ugKDOvRMFXQVuhDJlTCgCquCin&lang=python) is what you get (in this example, $M + v$). If you try another combination (like $M + u$ in the example), you'll see what happens. Let $M = (m_1, m_2, m_3)^T$. Then it returns
$$ M + v := (m_1 + v, m_2 + v, m_3 + v)^T $$
somehow. So it's a problem of Numpy and I think [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is more appropriate place to ask if you want to know why this happens.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have put a question on SO also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744402/numpy-matrix-plus-column-vector

Answer (score 5):

This is a case of less conventional notation used in deep learning: We
allow the addition of a matrix and a vector, yielding another matrix: $C = A+b$, where $C_{i,j}$ is $A_{i,j} + b_j$. See: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html (page 32)